# INNER JOIN doesn't work when LIMIT is added

Tags: mysql, limit, inner-join

here is the code I'm working with and works perfectly fine:

```
$curEvent_query = @mysql_query("SELECT ppl.Fname, ppl.Lname, ppl.Email, plans.ID, plans.Date FROM ppl INNER JOIN plans ON plans.ID IN ($List) AND plans.OwnerID=ppl.ID AND plans.Date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY plans.Date ASC");
```

But once I add the LIMIT, the code nolonger works:

```
$curEvent_query = @mysql_query("SELECT ppl.Fname, ppl.Lname, ppl.Email, plans.ID, plans.Date FROM ppl INNER JOIN plans ON plans.ID IN ($List) AND plans.OwnerID=ppl.ID AND plans.Date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY plans.Date ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage");
```

The reason for adding LIMIT is because I want to do paging. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by *"no longer works"*?

Comment: -1, because I decide for myself what is ASAP. -1 for not describing the way in which this "not works".

Comment: And what's the error returned?... How about generating that query string FIRST, and checking that it's valid?

Comment: The error I'm getting in return once I add the LIMIT is: "mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource"

But before the LIMIT, the query does work and pulls the correct data

Comment: And what is mysql_error() showing?

Comment: all that is showing is an error on this line:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /mypage.php on line 38

LINE 38: while($Event = mysql_fetch_array($curEvent_query)){

Comment: This is probably an SQL syntax error, maybe because of what is in the variables $offset. So viewing the executed query and the Mysql Error as shown in my post below can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the output of:

```
$query = "SELECT ppl.Fname, ppl.Lname, ppl.Email, plans.ID, plans.Date FROM ppl INNER JOIN plans ON plans.ID IN ($List) AND plans.OwnerID=ppl.ID AND plans.Date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY plans.Date ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";
echo $query;
$curEvent_query = mysql_query($query);
if (!$curEvent_query)
    echo mysql_error();
```

Comment: Ok I did what you asked, and it returned: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1, 1'

Comment: Ok after doing what you asked, I replaced the "-1" with "0" and the code worked! Thanks!... As you can tell I'm a programmer in progress but definitely appreciate the help guy!